# Why is details view button disabled on visual studio load test summary page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I ran a load test locally. After the test run "Detail" button on test summary page is disabled. What am I missing here?

[image: Load test summary page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the answer to this question myself so thought I would share here.

In order for the details view to be available, as far as I understand, the Timing Details Storage property of the load test run settings, must be set to All Individual Details - otherwise the details are not collected. It can be changed in the Run Settings for the load test.

See [this Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183356.aspx).

[Additional useful info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183349.aspx) on interpreting the details.